# Changing Column Data Type with FKs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, partitioning, foreign-key, table

I want to change my column data type from "Datetime" to "Datetime2(7)". If I try to do it with the GUI SQL Server 2014 asks to save all FKs table dependencies and then I get a lock timeout because this table has millions of rows. Is this possible while not losing the FKs dependencies and any data?

[image: Table Design]

It is a Test environment. The reason I want to do this is because I think I'm getting locks because of datetime precision (milliseconds). I have many rows with the same datetime and not ordered.

Comment: Have you tried using T-SQL statement? `ALTER TABLE [TABLE_NAME] ALTER COLUMN [COLUMN_NAME] datetime2;`

Comment: `I'm getting locks because of datetime precision` - are you _joining_ on a datetime column, or filtering for an exact point in time? I'm trying to understand how more precision is going to solve the problem (as opposed to just making it slightly different). Anyway the usual approach to something like this is to drop the foreign keys, then change the tables, then put the foreign keys back (and you can do this one by one to temper impact). How viable that is will depend on whether you can take any downtime at all or how much you trust your processes to *not* insert bad data in the meantime.

Comment: `datetime` to `datetime2` _should_ be an online operation, because there is no data loss, so it _should_ work like increasing the size of a `varchar` column, but that's not how it works today. In any case, doing it one by one should be faster than any process that tries to protect all the tables involved simultaneously (and, honestly, never try to do this kind of thing with the GUI, **especially** with big tables).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I haven't tested this either but I think it is a fundamental data type change because `datetime2` has a different structure than `datetime`. That will require updating every row. I completely the GUI isn't the right tool for this job.

Comment: @Dan yeah you might be right about the structure change.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to change the data type without data loss or breaking FK dependencies.  It depends on whether you have some downtime where you can execute the required change though.

Changing from `datetime` to `datetime2(7)` will require every row in the table / indexes to be updated, since these two types are stored differently on disk.  This can take a little time, depending on how many rows your table has (you said "millions").

The change would look like this in T-SQL (you should definitely do things like this in T-SQL rather than the GUI, by the way):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN CreationMoment datetime2(7);
```

The `ALTER` statement here requires SCH-M (schema modification) locks: on the table being changed, and on the tables that have foreign key relationships to this one.  That means that this statement will wait until there are no concurrent transactions before it's able to run.

Once it starts running, it will also *block* any concurrent activity on the tables until it completes.

Here's a toy example that creates a table with 10,000,000 rows with dates, and another table with 1,000 rows referencing the first table:

```
USE [master];
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT null FROM sys.databases d WHERE d.[name] = '248612') 
    DROP DATABASE [248612];
GO

CREATE DATABASE [248612];
GO
USE [248612];

CREATE TABLE dbo.DateTest
(
    Id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    SomeDate datetime NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.OtherTable
(
    Id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    DateTestId int NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT FK_OtherTable_DateTestId 
        FOREIGN KEY (DateTestId) 
        REFERENCES dbo.DateTest (Id)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.DateTest
SELECT TOP (10000000)
    DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 364 ), '2019-01-01')
FROM master.dbo.spt_values v1
    CROSS JOIN master.dbo.spt_values v2
    CROSS JOIN master.dbo.spt_values v3;

INSERT INTO dbo.OtherTable
SELECT TOP (1000)
    Id
FROM dbo.DateTest;
```

That code takes about 30 seconds to run on my machine.  With no other concurrent activity, the `ALTER` statement takes about 10-15 seconds:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.DateTest ALTER COLUMN SomeDate datetime2(7);
```

Ideally, you could do this kind of thing on a test system to assess about how long the blocking will be in production once the `ALTER` begins.

---

Regarding my "concurrent activity" statements, if I open a transaction and update a row in `dbo.DateTest`, the `ALTER` won't even start.  It sits and waits on the SCH-M lock that it needs, which you can see by running `sp_WhoIsActive @get_locks = 1`:

```xml
<Database name="248612">
  <Locks>
    <Lock request_mode="S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
  </Locks>
  <Objects>
    <Object name="DateTest" schema_name="dbo">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="Sch-M" request_status="WAIT" request_count="1" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
  </Objects>
</Database>
```

If I commit or rollback that update transaction, the `ALTER` starts, and I can see that it takes out locks on the `DateTest` and `OtherTable` tables (abbreviated XML here):

```xml
<Database name="248612">
  <Locks>
    <Lock request_mode="S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
  </Locks>
  <Objects>
    <Object name="DateTest" schema_name="dbo">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="Sch-M" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
    <Object name="FK_OtherTable_DateTestId" schema_name="dbo">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="Sch-M" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
    <Object name="OtherTable" schema_name="dbo">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="Sch-M" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
  </Objects>
</Database>
```

This will block writes on the tables involved until the `ALTER` completes.

Comment: Is it possible to do this if the modified column is part on a FK constraint?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ No, you would have to drop the FK first.

Comment: Thnx. But you can do it inside a transaction, right? (Drop the FK, Alter the 2 columns' type, Add the FK back). Asking because I'm not sure.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ you'd also have to drop the unique or primary key constraint on the table that the FK points to.  But yeah, you can do all of it in a transaction!